# 1:n relationship in MC

Tags: marketing-cloud

What is the best way to save generated leads from a website, that can request one or more product catalogues (1:n) in Marketing Cloud?

We want to save the lead itself and the catalogue downloads as seperate records, so we can use this information later for further segmentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save 1 record in a lead data extension and save the N records in a request table. Link the two tables with a 1:N relation via data designer.

The method for doing this is different based on your infrastructure. If the catalogue request is on cloud pages, you can use ampscript.

If it is on your own site, you can do it via various API calls.

And finally, if you don't require anything live - you can do it via file dumps on the FTP server - one for leads, one for requests.

Let me know if there is anything we can do to narrow down the answer :)

Comment: Awesome! :) Let me know if you need to explore further aspects of this, and hopefully it can be more concrete :)